# how to get the views listed in the WorkbenchWindow in RCP application?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In my `RCP` application there are two views.

I know how to get the active view. It's by using the following code:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActivePart();
```

But I need the list of all the views, which are present in the Active Workbench Window.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences()
```

for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

The views are on the page rather than the window:

```
IViewReference [] viewRefs = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences();
```

You can also get all pages (although there is usually only one)

```
IWorkbenchPage [] pages = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPages();
```

and windows:

```
IWorkbenchWindow [] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
```

To be sure you have everything iterate through all the pages on all the windows.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Keerthi use below code to get views,

PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViewReferences()

This will return arry of views iterator over the array and you will get each view.

To get view id, execute below

for(IViewPart view :PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getViews()){
          view.getViewSite().getId();//Get view id
        }

I hope this will definitely work for you :)